# How to use install4j to create a bundled jdk14?

Tags: install4j

How to use install4j to create a bundled jdk14?
I have tried for two days, however failed and failed again.
It seemed that I can't download the JDK14 bundled in install4j,
or make a suitable JDK14 bundle manually?
Could anyone please give me some advice?

Comment: I don't see any problem here. What version of install4j do you use and what error message to you get? Do you use generated or pre-created JRE bundles? What JDK base do you use?

Comment: I have tried again with "pack" option unchecked and problems solved. Thanks!!! Ingo.